# Menu doesn't display in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

[Can you check this page](http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/y/ogv.htm) and let me know why the menu doesn't work on IE7? It shows up all the way on the right, almost out of view.

The page works okay in other browsers (including IE8 and IE9). Thanks.

Comment: Not programming related, try doctype.com

Comment: @Harmen - people ask CSS/front end questions all the time on SO....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `postition:absolute;` to `position:relative;` in your #top-nav css ID. That will fix the position for you. After that remove `position:absolute;` from `#top-nav li p` and it will display correct.

I suggest you to download Developer Tools for IE. It helps you alot with HTML/CSS related problems when using IE.

Comment: I've got the tools installed for IE, but they simply don't give me the same experience as Firebug on FF :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have ul#top-nav set to display:none ?
If not that, try playing with position:absolute, you have there all over the place... IE may have issues concerning that.

Comment: Thanks, Jevgeni. What's weird is that it's only happening on IE7, not IE8, Firefox, Safari, or Chrome. I'm changing the display:none to display:block via JavaScript.